# Fee on transfer causing error "Uniswap invariant not satisfied"

Tags: erc-20, ether, uniswap, fees, transfer

I am working on building an ERC20 token with the help of the OpenZeppelin project.

I wanted to add a burn fee on transfer, so I overrode my transfer function as follows:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public virtual override returns (bool) {
  uint256 willBurn = _value / _burnRate;

  if (ERC20.transfer(_to, _value - willBurn)) {
    _burn(_msgSender(), willBurn);
    return true;
  } else return false;
}
```

And my transferFrom function as follows:

```
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public virtual override returns (bool) {
  uint256 willBurn = _value / _burnRate;

  if (ERC20.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value - willBurn)) {
    _burn(_from, willBurn);
    return true;
  } else return false; 
}
```

This works almost perfectly!

When I swap on uniswap, buying works fine, and selling it works fine if I change the number of tokens to sell. But when selling, if I change the amount of ETH that I want, it shows an error saying:

> The Uniswap invariant x*y=k was not satisfied by the swap. This usually means one of the tokens you are swapping incorporates custom behavior on transfer.

When researching, I found [another token that behaved in the exact same way](https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap?use=V2&inputCurrency=0x9f8eef61b1ad834b44c089dbf33eb854746a6bf9):

> [image]

This ONLY happens if you edit the amount of ETH to get out and click "Swap"

I found some information on this [error in uniswap's documentation](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts/common-errors/#fee-on-transfer-tokens), but I was wondering if there is a way for me to get around it? Does anyone know?

Comment: Is this UniswapV2 or V3? At least V2 had special trade functions for tokens which incorporate such internal fees

Comment: Yeah, it is uniswapV2, and it does work, but only if you change the token value. If you change the eth value it doesn't work at all.